# Return the response of a 2 "Synchronous" nested Queries (Express, Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, mongoose

I want to return an array of elements like this:

```
ApiResponse = [
   {_id: 1,
   name: Mike,
   transactions: 5},
   
    {_id: 2,
    name: Jhon,
    Transactions: 10}
]
```

The first data "Users" come from a query to the Schema "Users" , but the "Transactions" number comes from a query of other schema "Transactions"

I tried the next logic:

1. Get all the users using:
2. Iterate the "respUsers" array using map function:
3. for each "user" i got i want to query all transactions associated with:
4. then I just want the "length" the array so:
5. and to finish I want that the map function returns an array of objects like:

To finish with the next complete code for the api controller:

```
exports.list = async (req, res) => {
    //Find all users
    const respUsers = await User.find().exec();

    const responseArray = respUsers.map(async (user) => {
        let transactions = await Transactions.find({
            doctorOwner: user._id,
        }).exec();
        let transactionsLength = await transactions.length;

        return {
            _id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            transactions: transactionsLength 
        };
    });

    console.log(responseArray);

    res.json(responseArray);
};
```

but I got 3 empty arrays [],[],[]

and if I console.log on server side i got:

```
[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: try some thing like this,  let responseArray = await respUsers.map(async (promise, user) => {
    await promise;
//do your logic here
  }.Promise.resolve());

Comment: Sorry does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works. It was about `Promise.all()`. It creates a Promise which is resolved when all the other Promises inside are resolved.

```js
// Emulates User.find().exec()
async function getUsers() {
    return Promise.resolve([
        {
            _id: "id1",
            name: "John",
        },
        {
            _id: "id2",
            name: "Johny",
        },
        {
            _id: "id3",
            name: "Jonas",
        },
    ]);
}
// Emulates Transactions.find({} doctorOwner: user._id )
async function getTransactions() {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.round(Math.random() * 100); i++) {
        arr.push("transaction");
    }
    return Promise.resolve(arr);
}

const superFunc = async (req, res) => {
    // Find all users
    let respUsers = await getUsers();

    const responseArray = Promise.all(
        respUsers.map(async (user) => {
            let transactions = await getTransactions();
            let transactionsLength = transactions.length;

            const toReturn = {
                _id: user._id,
                name: user.name,
                transactions: transactionsLength,
            };
            return toReturn;
        })
    );

    console.log(await responseArray);
};

superFunc();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I add the await jus like you show and still got [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]

Comment: Strange. After having thought about it, it seems like the map function has done its job correctly, but it *returns* promises... I've made edits. What is the output now?

Comment: I make all the changes to the code that you gently propose me and I still got [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> }, Promise 
{ <pending> } ]

Comment: I debugged it and edited, here is the code! Of course, you should delete and replace the emulation functions, they are here just for the demo with the SO code snippet.